# to terminate write operation and close file in c++

Tags: c++

I am new to C++. I have written a small program to open a file and write in it with input from the user. I need to modify this program such that if the user enter a character like 'X' the program should close the input window and exit the program. I do not have any idea about how I can do it.
The code I have written is below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    std::ofstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open("C:\\UseCr\\pp\\qt_projects\\test.txt");
    string sInput;
    cout << "Please Enter the Text ";
    outputFile << sInput << endl;
    std::ifstream outputFile;
    output.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you want input from `stdin`? I'm confused where your input is supposed to come from.

Comment: If you have no idea, Stack Overflow is probably not the right place. look out for a forum for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

I might recommend something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

int main() {
    std::ofstream outputFile(filename); // This will open and close your file. Look up RAII

    string sInput;
    cout << "Please Enter the Text ";
    std::getline(cin, sInput); // Get a string from stdin, strip newline.
    // Check if it's a quit condition
    if(sInput == "x" || sInput == "X") { 
      cout << "Entered 'x', now exiting." << endl;
      qApp->quit(); // or something similar
    }
    // If it's not a quit condition, write to file
    outputFile << sInput << endl;
    // Once outputFile goes out of scope, it is closed.
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(){

        string sInput;
        std::ofstream outputfile;
        outputFile.open("C:\\UseCr\\pp\\qt_projects\\test.txt");
        cout << "Please enter the text : "<<endl;

        do{
            getline(cin,sInput); //it read from the keyboard what the user write and save into sInput variable
            outputfile << sInput<< endl;
        }while(sInput!= "X" || sInput != "x");
        outputFile.close();
        }
return 0;
}
```

`

Comment: There is error indication while compiling the while condition, as sInput is a string and the condition is as Character.